# adding node to a nodelist

Tags: java, loops, nodes, nodelist

my aim is to add nodes not at once to a NodeList but to add them in a loop in each iteration. i looked up the classes and methods for NodeList , but didnt find anything useful for it. is there anyway for doing this or should i use other interfaces?
going to do something like below but the NodeList interface doesnt have the "add" method.then how can i add items?

```
     static NodeList tryToGetThePoint;


    while(true)
       {
        .
        .
        .
    if(!"script".equals(myNode.getParentNode().getNodeName()))
{

tryToGetThePoint.add=myNode;

}
```

Comment: @deporter   of course a NodeList

Comment: *"of course"*  Why would someone ask if it were obvious?  Please take more care to use correct case for J2SE classes in future.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Seems like a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The critical bit about this is:

"The NodeList interface provides the abstraction of an ordered collection of nodes, without defining or constraining how this collection is implemented."

In short: it's up to you to implement everything.

Are you sure you can't use Lists instead? I mean, it depends what this is for?

But if you do want to implement your own, this is roughly how it should be.

```
public class MyNodeList implements NodeList {
    Node root = null;
    int length = 0;
    public MyNodeList() {}

    public void addNode(Node node) {
        if(root == null)
            root = node;
        else
            root.addChild(node);
        length++;
    }

    public Node item(int index) {
        if(index < 1) return root;
        Node node = root;
        while(index > 0) {
           node = node.getFirstChild();
           if(node == null) return node;
           index--;
        }
        return node;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example has me a bit lost - where are the item and getLength methods? And why do you implement Node as well? Otherwise, I agree.

Comment: Ok. I would have just used an underlying List though, which of course makes the whole NodeList thing a bit pointless.

Comment: I just copy-pasted that example code and it is not working. As soon as you have more than 2 items it falls apart, because all items are added as children to the root, but when "item(int index)" is called it is going for the child of the child, etc. sorry can't explain this better in a rush

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember that the nodes in a `NodeList` are *live* - if you change them you are modifying the underlying DOM tree. Therefore it doesn't really make sense to add things to a `NodeList` - where do you expect them to live in the tree?

If you just want a list of `Node`s unconnected with the document, just use `List<Node>`. Otherwise, you will need to figure out where to add the nodes to the DOM tree and use the normal methods.

UPDATE: I didn't notice you were declaring the `NodeList` - this won't work unless you implement it yourself as Perry Monschau says. Just use `List<Node>` instead.

Comment: oh i see. yea i wanted a list of nodes but just wondering if NodeList can do it too. thank you for your advice :)

Comment: Yes, NodeList is really just a return type for various DOM methods.